# Displaying images from an tempImage to imgsrc using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code which tries to display temporary images from `tempimages[]` to `img` `src` with `id=slide` of `box002` ,according to the random number selected from `arrayVariable` to `ptag[i]` .

I have used function `displayAllImages()` to allocate images to `img` `src` `id=slide`. but it failed to display images.

my problem is im not able to display tempimages array to img sr of box002.

how to achieve it?

```js
var tempimages = [];

function rvalue() {
    var array = [];
    var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
    var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg' ,'5.jpg','6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg' ,'10.jpg']; //your assumed   
    arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
    ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");

    for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
        ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
        array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
        tempimages.push(`${ptags[i].textContent}.jpg`); 
    }
  
    console.log(array);
    console.log(tempimages); 
    console.log(slide); 
}
  
function displayAllImages() {
    var i = 0,
        len = tempimages.length;        
    
    for (; i < tempimages.length; i++) {   
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = tempimages[i];
        img.style.width = '100px';
        img.style.height = '100px';
        document.getElementById('slide').appendChild(img);
    }
};

$(function() {
    displayAllImages();   
});
```

```css
#container {
    margin-top:15%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:30%;
}

.box {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #333;
    border-color: #e6e600;
    margin:-2px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background-color:  #66ff66;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
        <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
        <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
        <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
    <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:49px; height:49px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>    
</div>    
</body>
```